# Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"" | "," | " " | "."'

Tags: typescript

In my class I have a property:

```
thousandSeparator: '' | ',' | ' ' | '.';
```

and want to set it by:

```
const options = {
  thousandSeparator: ','
};
```

when setting this I get the error

```
 Types of property 'thousandSeparator' are incompatible.
 Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"" | "," | " " | "."'.
```

Comment: `options.thousandSeparator` should be const if you want to assign it to type `'' | ',' | ' ' | '.'`

Comment: TLDR: use `const options =  { thousandSeparator: ',' as const };` so `','` is actually of type `','` and not widened to type `'string'`.

Comment: Why is this question being labelled a duplicate? It is not. The linked question involves a variable with a type string and another variable with a type of a set of string values and attempting to set one variable to the other. This question is about defining a property on an object with a set of string values.

Comment: The code in tsc playground link is the correct answer for the response below, not what is shown in the response. The problem is that you need to define `options` with a property `thousandSeparator: '' | ',' | ' ' | '.';`, as represented in the tsc link by `type optionsType = { thousandSeparator : '' | ',' | ' ' | '.'; };` and then `const options:optionsType = { thousandSeparator: ',' };` Above, you've defined a variable, not an object property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine in the [tsc playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA9mwEsYDsDOAVc0C8UDeAUFMVMABYwCuqAhsgCYDKEYNATjcDG1AFxQByAVAA%20ggDTCxwqYIB0A8QQC%20AbgIEAxilTBY8JGl5xEOzJCi5CxclVoNmrDlzb9Fileq06YAGwhyvjAA5gAUJoaoAJRAA)

If there is more to your code, such as defining the string elsewhere before setting it to the variable, you will have to cast it, like so:

```
type thousandSeparator = '' | ',' | ' ' | '.';

const options = {
  thousandSeparator: ',' as thousandSeparator,
};
```